# phpmyadmin can't click users tab

Tags: 14.04, mysql, phpmyadmin

I finally managed to install mysql-server-5.7 and phpmyadmin. I got root permissions, can log in with it everywhere, etc. What I can't do is to get to the Users tab in phpmyadmin web panel.  Clicking there does nothing, or maybe just refreshes page because warning from main page (different versions of php installed) disappears.

How to regain access to this panel?

Answer (score 1):

I've got it working after upgrading to PhpMyAdmin-4.7.0.

Hope this can help someone with same issue.

BR.